# Scalable solution for thousands of background jobs each of them opening web sockets

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, task, jobs

I'm working on a crypto bot platform, which is pulling data off exchanges like Binance and offers bots to its users. These bots are running as background jobs. Each one of these bots subscribes to the following [exchange web sockets](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md): order book, trade history, candlestick chart data, open orders, account transactions, account balances, etc. The bots are using these web socket subscriptions from the exchanges and based on a strategy they execute orders. The backend also hosts SignalR hubs (wss://url), which is supposed to update the UI in realtime.

#### The issue

I'm unable to scale the background jobs for the bots. How do the big platforms handle so many bots at the same time? They are running like 300,000 bots at the same time.

Each bot requires at least 4 sockets (1 - order book, 2 - trade history, 3 - candlestick data, 4 - account information e.g. balances, etc.).
The web sockets related to the account information have its own listen key, which means they cannot be reused, unlike the others that they don't require that listen key.

I've seen one of these platforms' Network tab in the browser and it seems to be using only one URL *wss://...*, which means they are running on a single machine?

[image]

#### Math:

- 300,000 bots
- 4 sockets per bot (3 of them can be reused, which leaves 1 socket per bot)
  =
  300,000 sockets at the same time

#### How many sockets is possible to handle on a single machine/server

> Each registered file descriptor costs roughly 90 bytes on a 32-bit kernel, and roughly 160 bytes on a 64-bit kernel.

160 bytes per socket = 1.600.000 sockets per machine, which means 300,000 bots should be alright, but I still need know about a scalable solution, because imagine the amount of the users increases in the future. These bot background jobs have to be split between different machines/servers or something.

#### What I tried

I tried Hangfire back in the time, but I'm not an expert and I don't know if it's a good solution.

Comment: Do you have any code you could share as to how you are doing it now? Would make it easier to point you in a specific direction. Typically you want to use socket asynchronous call backs.

Comment: @Selthien, thank you for your answer! You need the source code for the 1) background jobs for the bots (I have an old code which doesn't look good - I'm currently recreating the whole project), 2) the hubs which are supposed to keep the UI updated or 3) the web socket subscription to Binance's web socket streams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It is the Round Robin/Weighted Robin Load Balancer of the IIS, Nginx or any server.

> Round robin load balancing is a simple way to distribute client requests across a group of servers. A client request is forwarded to each server in turn. The algorithm instructs the load balancer to go back to the top of the list and repeats again.

Ardalis documented it on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#monolithic-applications-and-containers).